# sql select query issue in python

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I am running following command to fetch data of particular customer but output comes out to be null or no data found, while data is already stored in the table. Can anyone identify the problem

```
custid=input("Enter CustomerID:")  
cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM INFYCAMPUSCONNECT.CUSTOMER WHERE CUSTOMERID= :1 """ , (custid))
```

Comment: Just tried using %s. It give following error:cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

Comment: We need more information. Which database backend are you using? Which module do you use to connect to it? What are you typing? What is the type of the column in the database? What results do you get? Edit the question and add full error traceback?

Comment: @nosklo The error message indicates that he's using Oracle.

Comment: @Barmar :1 is correct for some databases. Unfortunately there is no information in the question.

Comment: It has the `oracle` tag as well.

Comment: Try changing `(custid)` to `(custid,)` so it's a tuple.

Comment: I am using Oracle database. Type of column is char(5). I am giving input as: C0002. And the ouput is: []

Comment: @nosklo I didn't realize the placeholder syntax was dependent on the DB, I thought it was more generic. `:1` is correct for Oracle.

Comment: @Barmer I tried using (custid,) but still no benefit of that

Comment: @Barmar Actually it did solve my problem subsequently. Thanks mate

Comment: @AniketJain:Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

The parameters need to be a tuple, so you have to put a comma in the parentheses:

```
cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM INFYCAMPUSCONNECT.CUSTOMER WHERE CUSTOMERID= :1 """ , (custid,))
```